# How to avoid duplicate entries in a MySQL database without throwing an error

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am using the Python-MySQL (MySQLdb) library to insert values into a database. I want to avoid duplicate entries from being inserted into the database, so I have added the `unique` constraint to that column in MySQL. I am checking for duplicates in the `title` column. In my Python script, I am using the following statement:

```
cursor.execute ("""INSERT INTO `database` (title, introduction) VALUES (%s, %s)""", (title, pure_introduction))
```

Now when a duplicate entry is added to the database, it will produce an error. I do not want an error message to appear; I just want that if a duplicate entry is found then it should simply not enter that value into the database. How do I do this?

Comment: Take a look at [INSERT IGNORE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/548570/189134)

Comment: wow! sometimes small changes can do wonder!!! Hope i could mark it as an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can utilize the [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) syntax to suppress this type of error.

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors may generate warnings instead, although duplicate-key errors do not.

In your case, the query would become:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `database` (title, introduction) VALUES (%s, %s)
```

Comment: Note that this will potentially ignore a whole swathe of other errors that could occur. (The quote from the docs does say this, but it's worth repeating!)

Answer (score 9):

Aside from what @Andy suggested (which should really be posted as an answer), you can also catch the exception in Python and silence it:

```
try:
    cursor.execute ("""INSERT INTO `database` (title, introduction) VALUES (%s, %s)""", (title, pure_introduction))
except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
    pass  # or may be at least log?
```

Comment: As a side question, where could I find documentation for cursor? I searched for it and I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor) but it seems to be insufficient.

Comment: @sємsєм for example, [here](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors-module.html) (MySQLdb specifically).

Comment: +one this is surely a good alternative to similar sounding issues!

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation does not show what does it return on errors? @alecxe

Comment: @sємsєм as for `MySQLdb` - yes, [documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) really sucks.

Comment: it seems that the `MySQLdb.IntegrityError`  only provides `args` attribute , which is a short list describing the cause of error , `IntegrityError.args[0]` shows error code defined in mysql ,  `IntegrityError.args[1]` is a formatted string text describing the detail, which is not really convenient because you may need to extract words from the formatted string text.