# ValueError: Could not process parameters in Python/MySQL

Tags: python, parameters, valueerror

I want to prevent duplicate usernames when people register.

Here is my code snippet:

```
def submit(self):
    username_info = username.get()
    username_password = password.get()
  
    #connect to db
    db = mysql.connector.connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'root', password = '', database = 'user')

    #create a cursor
    mycursor = db.cursor()
    #insert to db
    sql = ("INSERT INTO useraccess (user_type, password) VALUES (%s, %s)")

    query = (username_info, username_password)
    mycursor.execute(sql, query)
    #commit
    db.commit()

    #create a messagebox
    messagebox.showinfo("Registration", "Successfully Register")

    #if username has been used
    find_user = ("SELECT * FROM useraccess WHERE user_type = ?")
    user_query = (username_info)

    mycursor.execute(find_user, user_query)
    #if (username == username_info):
    if mycursor.fetchall():
        messagebox.showerror("Registration", "The username chosen is already used. Please select another username")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Registration", "Account Created!")
```

But every time I run it, although the username has been registered in the db, it only shows the successfully created messagebox and error:

> ValueError: Could not process parameters.

Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to make sure your query variables are tuples.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe the source of the problem is in the line

```
user_query = (username_info)
```

It should be

```
user_query = (username_info,)
```

The trailing comma is the syntactic  difference between an expression in parentheses and a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-tuple).

Another issue with code is the query:

```
find_user = ("SELECT * FROM useraccess WHERE user_type = ?")
```

Which should be:

```
find_user = ("SELECT * FROM useraccess WHERE user_type = %s")
```

Comment: when i change it to user_query = (username_info,) , it shows another error which is mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: @Eve11 The `?` in your second query string is not a valid placeholder for parameters in `mysql.connector`. You need to change that to `%s`.

Comment: Updated answer with fix for the second issue

Comment: Thanks, coming here from a whole different case, but with the same root problem. It did not detect the variable as a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked these variables,

```
username_info = username.get()
username_password = password.get()
```

are they in proccesable formats? (i.e. can you directly put the username.get() into user_type ?)

I'm not familiar with this way of passing a parameter

```
find_user = ("SELECT * FROM useraccess WHERE user_type = ?")
```

have you double checked this? (why not the %s method?)

also, you probably get the "Account Created!" because mycursor.fetchall() fails.

Comment: I change it to  #if username has been used
        find_user = ("SELECT * FROM useraccess WHERE user_type = %s")
        user_query = (username_info, )

        mycursor.execute(find_user, user_query)
        #if (username == username_info):
        if mycursor.fetchall():
            messagebox.showerror("Registration", "The username chosen is already used. Please select another username")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Registration", "Account Created!")

Comment: now when i run that code, there is no error. But it only shows "The username chosen is already used. Please select another username" messagebox, but the username is duplicated in the db

Comment: Its because you insert the new user before you check if theres a duplicate;

Comment: nb. mycursor.execute(sql, query)  already adds the duplicate before you check if theres going to be a duplicate (advies: run the insert after checking if theres a duplicate)

Comment: @Eve11 Or, use a [unique constraint](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/) on the column holding the user name. You'll have to handle `IntegrityError`s on the INSERT or use INSERT IGNORE. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787472/how-to-avoid-duplicate-entries-in-a-mysql-database-without-throwing-an-error)