# check if duplicate value is being added to mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am creating a program to practice MySQL where there is a table called inventory and the user adds to the table

```
item_code   item_name    price   quantity 
a000        a            100     100
```

I want to make it so that if the user inputs a000 then he gets a message of the item_code already being in the table
is there any way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a UNIQUE index on the `item_code` field.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX item_code_unique
ON inventory(item_code);
```

You can then use a `try-catch` block to catch any error from inserting duplicates.

```py
try:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ....")
except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
    print("Duplicate entry")
```

See also: [How to avoid duplicate entries in a MySQL database without throwing an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787472/how-to-avoid-duplicate-entries-in-a-mysql-database-without-throwing-an-error)

[Using MySQL UNIQUE Index To Prevent Duplicates](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("NameOfYourDatabase.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS inventory (
                      item_code text UNIQUE,
                      item_name text,
                      price INT,
                      quantity INT
                      )"""
try:
   #INSERT whatever you want into the db here 

except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
   print("Item code already exists")
```

---

You can also make your item_code a `PRIMARY KEY` as a `PRIMARY KEY` is automatically set as `UNIQUE`

REMEMBER: You can have only one `PRIMARY KEY` per table.

If your table is already created:

```
ALTER TABLE inventory
   MODIFY item_code text NOT NULL UNIQUE;
```

With `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
ALTER TABLE inventory
ADD PRIMARY KEY (item_code);
```

Learn more in this website:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp